# How to merge cells in pages

Tags: pages

I followed the instructions to merge cells as mentioned on the apple page :

select 2 cells > press format > but there are no such a button writing "merge cells"?!

Is there a problem with my pages?
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

- Select several cells
- In the Menu, select **Format** -- **Table**
- Should be the second menu item from the bottom